# Do red cross signs on the street mean I am not allowed to drive into this alley in Seattle?

Tags: usa, legal, driving, seattle, washington-state

I saw alley this alley:

[image]

[Google Street view](https://www.google.com/maps/place/1110+E+Pine+St,+Seattle,+WA+98122,+USA/@47.6152924,-122.3175208,3a,33.7y,187.38h,77.75t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1ssllWP7-V_UO77HDvDyknOw!2e0!7i16384!8i8192!4m5!3m4!1s0x54906acda12a468d:0xdc50175788531ed2!8m2!3d47.615378!4d-122.3175877)

The presence of the red crossses at the entrance of the alley (= the bottom of the picture) makes me wonder whether I am allowed to drive into this alley. Do red cross signs on the street mean I am not allowed to drive into this alley in Seattle?

The red crossses at the entrance of the alley are the only signs I saw. I didn't enter the alley since I was in a car and unwilling to pay a fine, so I don't know whether or connected to another street.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129652/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-do-red-cross-signs-on-the-street-me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important point here is that the alley in question does not go through. It's blocked off on one end by a fence. It's also very narrow, and might be narrowed further by garbage cans and other obstacles.

I don't know who put the red X's there or why. That's not a standard traffic marking and carries no legal meaning. But it does a pretty good job of indicating that no good comes from driving into there unless you know what you're doing. Driving in there leaves you in a (literally) tight spot where you have to back up a long way in a narrow space and reverse over a sidewalk and (awful) bike lane to get out. It's possible someone put the X's there to try to deter people from randomly driving in, not because it's a legal street marking, but because it doesn't go through, and they were tired of random drivers blocking up their alley or parking illegally.

Finally, one other key detail: this alley is behind a police station. While I can't see any legal signage on Street View prohibiting you from driving into it, the police next door may wonder what you're up to, and may be unamused if you're driving into a dead-end alley next to their station without any apparent lawful purpose.

Comment: If you've got a reason to be in there, it's best to back *in* not out (see the truck in the background of the picture).  Then you're not coming out blind into pedestrians.  This is especially important for things like delivery vans with poor rearward lines of sight

Comment: The police may be unamused, but as the alley seems to be a publicly accessible they have no right to do anything but be unamused.  Now, they may pretend that they can do more than be unamused, but that doesn't change facts.  And then there is a whole subsection of people out there doing "First amendment audits" of police stations by remaining solidly in their valid legal with the apparent purpose of making the police feel uncomfortable with the expectation that the actions of the police will exceed their legal authority.

Comment: Sure, but this is a travel site, and driving into narrow dead-end alleys without any purpose is just kind of broadly inconsiderate of everyone around you. If your goal is to intentionally attempt to provoke confrontations with the police for the purpose of trying to catch them acting illegally, whatever you're doing isn't really in the realm of "travel" anymore.